# SQL: read from notepad and check values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a notepad file with 50k account IDs. I have access to a read only database through SQL Workbench J and I'm trying to get data when account_id matches one of the IDs in Notepad.

I understand I need to do account_id IN (my list of ID's). But given that 50k accounts is too much to paste, I want to read the accounts directly from Notepad itself, but I am not able to figure out the best way to do so.

I only have read only permission so creating a new table or column with the information in the Notepad file is a no-go. I'm not really familiar enough with SQL to figure out the best way to do so.

Comment: What format is your file in?

Comment: 50k entries is likely too many for an IN clause.

Comment: You should be able to create a temporary table.